# What is the Fourier transform of the relativistic energy dispersion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of the relativistic energy dispersion for the massive and massless case? This is a question of Schwartz QFT at the end of Part II. I managed to write it in terms of Hankel functions for the massive case, which I hope is right, but the massless case gives me zero.

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(\vec{x},\vec{y})&=\int \frac{\text{d}^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \; e^{i\vec{p}\cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{y})} \; \sqrt{p^2+m^2}\\
&=e^{i11 \pi/4}\frac{4\pi^2m^2}{r^2}H^{(1)}_{5/2}(imr),
\end{align}
where $r=|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|$, I don't know if this is correct but for $m\rightarrow0$ this is infinite which is weird.Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't think the $m \rightarrow 0$ limit is supposed to be singular. Could you please show your working?

Comment: Moreover, Weinberg (9.2.13) gives the solution as $\mathcal{E}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \frac{m}{2\pi^2 r}\frac{d}{dr}(\frac1r K_{-1}(mr))$